# Server (example.com) refuses to send mail to name@example.com

Tags: zend-framework, email, google-apps

I'll start out with my configuration:

- example.com mailserver - Google Apps.
- example.com - has regular mailings based on queries, sent out daily and weekly.  Build in Zend framework, with extJS.
- subdomain.example.com - to process the bulk mailings.

Background: I enjoy using google apps features (CRM, calendar, mail, etc), but due to my mail volume I can't send all of my outbound alerts through Google Apps.  To work around this, I set up a subdomain on my server and am running my email off of that account.

Problem:  I  have mail that is generated from example.com, and sent to me@example.com.  My server refuses to send this mail and it lands in the root email account. All other emails are delivered without an issue (yahoo, hotmail, yoursite.com, gmail, ...)

I've worked on this all day and can't seem to come up with a solution (aside from sending emails to an outside account).

Has anyone experienced this before?  How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  I had to log into WHM and select that my mail not deliver mail locally.

Main >> DNS Functions >> Edit MX Entry

REMOTE MAIL EXCHANGER: This server will NOT serve as a mail exchanger for containerauction.com's mail.: This configuration has been manually selected.